# How to filter array model data based on user input in text field

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, filter, textfield

I having the `array` model data I load that data into `tableview`.

I want to make the search functionality for that `tableview`. I take the text field and based on user input I filter that `array` and `reload` the `tableview`.

please find my code bellow.

in `tableview`

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

           let model = array[indexPath.row]

            if let rate = model.price
            {
                cell.pricelbl.text = "$" + rate
            }
            cell.namelbl.text = model.prodName ?? ""

            if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
                cell.uiview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            } else {
                cell.uiview.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightBaground
                cell.uiview.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            }
  }

//Textfield delegate methods.

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField == searchtextfield
        {
            var foundItems = [BaseApparel]()
            foundItems = self.array.filter { $0.prodName == searchtextfield.text! }
            self.array = foundItems

            self.searchtableview.reloadData()
        }
         return true
    }
```

Comment: where is your filtering code?

Comment: you should always keep an original array before it is filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Use two fields for data: `array` and `filteredArray`.

By default array and filteredArray should be same:

```
let array : Array<String> = ["1", "2", "3"];
var filteredData = Array<String>() {
    didSet{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    filteredData = array
}
```

Use filteredData array to produce cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.filteredData.count
    }
```

Update filteredData and reloadTable if user changed text:

```
@objc func textChangedNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        self.filteredData = self.array.filter { $0.prodName == searchtextfield.text! }
    }
```

Use [textDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619640-textdidchangenotification) to observe text changing in the text field.